# How do I abstract repetitive selector from this Less code?

Tags: css, less

I have a number of Less codes blocks which can be repetitive - here's a simple example :

```
.span-@{outer-index}-of-@{max-grid} .row:first-of-type .span-@{outer-index}-of-@{max-grid}
```

As you can see the first and last sections are exactly the same.

I've been trying to work out how to create an @item variable and use it in the following way, but have been unable to get the code to compile due to syntax issues:

```
@item:.span-@{outer-index}-of-@{max-grid};

@item .row:first-of-type @item {}
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, bad example - I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of minor problems with the code that you were trying but on the whole you were on the correct path. Making the following corrections would solve the issue.

1. When trying to concatenate variable values to a string and get the concatenated string as output, you should put the whole thing within quotes like shown below. **Note** that when you put the whole thing within quotes, Less would print the output value also with quotes which we don't need because we would be using it in a selector. Hence, we should use the `~()` or the `e()` functions to strip the quotes from output.

   ```
   @item:~".span-@{outer-index}-of-@{max-grid}";
   ```
2. Secondly, when using a variable in selector interpolation to form a selector dynamically, the variable should be of the form `@{variable-name}` (within curly braces) and so for your case it should be modified to be like below:
   `@{item} .row:first-of-type @{item} {
       color: blue;
   }`

Finally, the approach suggested earlier by Eric would/should also work if we make the same change as mentioned in Point 2 above (due to selector interpolation being used). However, when this whole selector is nested within another parent, the `&` (parent selector) would always mean the whole parent upto the top-most level and hence it might not work as expected for all cases.

For example, consider a nesting scenario like below:

```
.foo{
    @{item} {
        & .row:first-of-type & {foo:bar;}
    }
}
```

When compiled, the above would produce the following CSS. Here we can see how the `.foo` parent comes both at the start and the end.

```
.foo .span-1-of-3 .row:first-of-type .foo .span-1-of-3 {
  foo: bar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any luck with this?

```
@item {
    & .row:first-of-type & {}
}
```